# Combo boxes duplicate entries

Tags: c#, combobox

I am adding items to combo box using `comboBox.Items.Add(entry);`. But how can I avoid duplicate entries (i.e same name entries) in combobox. Is there any lib function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check for the item before adding:

```
if (!comboBox.Items.Contains(entry))
    comboBox.Items.Add(entry);
```

Comment: thanxs. Moreover is there any function which does the same for `Items.AddRange`

Comment: No. Just check them all in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

The `Items` collection has a `Contains` method

```
if (!comboBox.Items.Contains(entry)) {
    comboBox.Items.Add(entry);
}
```

---

The `ComboBox.Items` property is of type `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection`, which declares the `Contains` method like this

```
public bool Contains(object value)
```

---

If you want to use `AddRange`, you must provide the items in an array. Therefore you must make sure that this array does not contain duplicates. Moreover, if the `ComboBox` already contains items, you must make sure that this array does not contain the same items.

Let's first assume that the `ComboBox` is empty and that your items are given by some enumeration (this could be a `List<T>` or an array for instance):

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(
    itemsToAdd
        .Distinct()
        .ToArray()
);
```

You must have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code. Also you might want to order the items. I assume that they are of `string` type:

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(
    itemsToAdd
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(s => s)
        .ToArray()
);
```

---

If the ComboBox already contains items, you will have to exclude them from the added items

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(
    itemsToAdd
        .Except(comboBox.Items.Cast<string>())
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(s => s)
        .ToArray()
);
```

(Again assuming that `itemsToAdd` is an enumeration of strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Use an [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class to bind the control, how depens from the presentation technology, or use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method of LINQ to filter duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

How about Casting the items to `String`

```
var check = comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(c => c.ToString() == "test");
```