# how can i avoid getting duplicates in a combo box and make sure that my combo boxes always get the values they are supposed to get?

Tags: c#, forms, combobox, iteration, datasource

I used the following link but it did not work
[Combo boxes duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800791/combo-boxes-duplicate-entries)

The data is:

Printer, Epson, T200

Mainframe, IBM, z15

Mainframe, Del, X99

This information comes from a database but it is all there and tested so I left the irrelevant code out.

So I have two problems. The first one is that the EquipmentType Combo box
repeats values. I have 2 mainframes, so it shows mainframe twice. 
The second problem is that if i go through the EquipmentType combo box,
and return to a previous value, the EquipmentModel does not update until i open
the EquipmentName combobox physically click on an entry

```
private void Client_Maintenance_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    cmbicEquipmentType.DataSource = equip;
    cmbicEquipmentType.DisplayMember = "EquipmentType";

    cmbicEquipmentName.DataSource = equipmentName;
    cmbicEquipmentModel.DataSource = equipmentModel;
}

private void cmbicEquipmentType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    nameSource.Clear();
    foreach (Equipment item in equip)
        {
            if (item.EquipmentType == cmbicEquipmentType.Text)
                {
                    nameSource.Add(item.EquipmentName);
                    cmbicEquipmentName.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }               

        }
    nameSource.DataSource = null;
    nameSource.DataSource = equipmentName;
    cmbicEquipmentName.DataSource = nameSource;
    cmbicEquipmentName.Update();
    cmbicEquipmentName.Refresh();
}

private void cmbicEquipmentName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    nameSource2.Clear();   
    foreach (Equipment item in equip)
        {
            if (item.EquipmentName == cmbicEquipmentName.Text)
                {
                    nameSource2.Add(item.EquipmentModel);
                    cmbicEquipmentModel.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }

    nameSource2.DataSource = null;            
    nameSource2.DataSource = equipmentModel;

    cmbicEquipmentModel.DataSource = nameSource2;
    cmbicEquipmentModel.Update();
    cmbicEquipmentModel.Refresh();

}
```

This is the combo box that shows the duplicates
[image]

Equipment model does not update
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift you content quality up

Comment: I checked the link but I am still unclear. Did I put in too much code or too little code? I tried to keep the code as relevant as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!cmbicEquipmentType.Items.Contains(item.EquipmentType.ToString()))
                    {
                        cmbicEquipmentType.Items.Add(item.EquipmentType.ToString());
                    }
```

This fixed the duplication problem. I adapted my program to make the 2nd problem look like its supposed to happen.